# Can't get a div to position the way i want it to

Tags: html, css

This is a site I am working on for a school project.The page is in Dutch, sorry. http://v14ewoude.helenparkhurst.net/index.html I am trying to get my div to cover up all of my content. But it keeps sticking at my header. I can't get it to work. Could someone look it up for me? Thanks in advance.

Heres a part of my code:

```
   <body><div id="wrapper">
<img class="logo" src="images/ericvanderwoude.png" alt="Eric van der Woude" height="150" width="150">
    <header>
        <h1>Informatica Opdracht</h1>
    </header>
    <nav id="menu">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>   

    </nav>

    <section class="fullwidth">
        <h3>Opdracht</h3>
        <p>De opdracht was een site te maken met behulp van HTML5 en CSS. Als hulpbronnen mocht ik onder andere de cursus op <a href="http://informatica-actief.stoas.nl/login/index.php" target="_blank">Informatica Actief</a> gebruiken en de informatie van <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">W3Schools.</a></p>
        <h3>Eisen</h3>
        <p>Volgens de opdracht moest ik mij aan een aantal eisen houden, namelijk de site moest minimaal een startscherm, hoofdscherm en minimaal 1 scherm vanuit het menu in het rechtergedeelte. Ik moest zo veel mogelijk laten zien wat ik van HTML5 en CSS afweet. De opmaak moet geheel met CSS zijn gemaakt en de pagina moet een favicon hebben.</p>
    </section>

    <article>



        <h3>Kolom</h3>
        <p>Voor het gemak heb ik het onderwerp 'salaris' gekozen. Overigens heb ik de &lt;th&gt; of table header niet meegerekend als kolom.</p>
        <table style="width:100%">
        <caption>Salarissen</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Maand</th>
                <th colspan="4">Salaris</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rex</td>
                <td>Emily</td>
                <td>Marcel</td>
                <td>Julia</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Januari</td>
                <td>€95</td>
                <td>€110</td>
                <td>€70</td>
                <td>€45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Februari</td>
                <td>€70</td>
                <td>€60</td>
                <td>€85</td>
                <td>€95</td>

            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Maart</td>
                <td>€145</td>
                <td>€40</td>
                <td>€60</td>
                <td>€80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>April</td>
                <td>€85</td>
                <td>€110</td>
                <td>€98</td>
                <td>€100</td>       
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </article>
    <aside>
        <h4>Extra opgaven</h4>
        <p>Er werd ook een extra opgave gegeven. Deze zal ik hieronder beschrijven.</p>
        <p>"Je hebt een 4 rijen, 5 kolommen tabel, met de tabel functionaliteit van HTML en geheel met CSS gemaakt. De tabel moet voorzien van een eerste speciale rij en kolom. Elke cel in de tabel moet van een rand voorzien zijn (lijnen zichtbaar)"</p>
    </aside>
    <footer>
    <p>Copyright&copy; 2014 - Eric van der Woude - Informatica Helen Parkhurst</p>
    </footer>
    </div>          
    </body>
```

and heres a part of my css:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url('/images/background_graygoose_noise.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color:white;
}
#menu{
    background-color: #44699C;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:90%;
}
article, section{
    margin: 1.858736%; /* 10px/538px=0.1858736*100=~1.858736 */
}
article, section{
    float: left;
    width: 63.197026%; /* 340px/538px=0.631970*100=~63.197026 */
}
aside{
    float: right;
    width: 29.638029%; /* 158/538px=0.293680*100=~29.638029 */
}
footer{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin: 1.858736%; /* 10px/538px=0.1858736*100=~1.858736 */
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Can't figure out where the problem is. Do you mean the background image?

Comment: The special row within your table should be a `<th></th>` (stands for table header) for your extra assignment.

Comment: @Dorvalla Which one do you mean?

Comment: The ones where you define the names of those who gets the salery (so the names of Rex, Emlily, Marcel and Julia) Make those cells `<th></th>` instead of `<td></td>` since they are not 'data'. Check here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using float...which means your wrapper doesn't count those divs, so it sticks to the only thing that's not floating. The solution is to remove the floats and find alternatives. hope this helps

Comment: The alternative being position: absolute;

Comment: using position absolute is the same, the wrapper won't count those as actual blocks either

Comment: I removed all of my floats and it now positions the way I tried to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

put that line before you want to change float or change line

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element in Chrome and look at the Computed tab next to Styles you will see for background repeat that

```
repeat-x
```

overrides

```
repeat-y
```

if you require both to repeat, simply put:

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```